Prediction using arima but showing error in Python
Here's the code using statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.Arima model to predict the store sales
from statsmodels.tsa.arima.model import ARIMA
from datetime import datetime

# fit model
model = ARIMA(ts, order=(1,0,1)) 
model_fit = model.fit()

# predict
start_index = datetime(2024, 1, 1)
end_index = datetime(2024, 5, 1)
# model_fit.predict(start=start_index, end=end_index)
forecast = model_fit.predict(start = "2024-01-01", end = "2024-05-01")

However, it just shows ValueError: Prediction must have `end` after `start`.
Is there anyone having the same issue as well?
ts is a dataframe with two columns, date(index, from 2021/01/01 to 2024/05/02) and gmv

date          gmv
2021-01-01    155629555
2021-01-02    161346990
...
...
2024-01-01    192776022
...
2024-05-01    207816942
2024-05-02    217788026


Make sure to define ts and the date range for prediction correctly. In this case, you will need to supply start and end parameters to the predict function in the format that is compatible with the index of the time series.
